# how to code a condition: 'can this string be converted into a date type'? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, date

can I code this condition in ruby somehow? I need to know **if a string can be converted into a date** variable. The only way how to do it is Date.parse("my string") and exception. Is there any other way?

```
date_scraped_from_the_net = "20 Dec 2009" or it could be "today"

if date_scraped_from_the_net is not a date type 
  needs_to_be_updated = true
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need sophisticated date parsing, I would try [this](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/).

However, if I understand your specific question, you'll want to use `rescue` to use methods that raise errors in conditionals:

```
if (Date.parse(date_scraped_from_the_net) rescue nil)
  needs_to_be_updated = true
end
```

Comment: @floyd: your code is not working for me.I thought there would some other `easier way` how to do it. PS chronic look very goooood.

Comment: it is working now.Thank you.I'll wait for a while if anybody else have any idea otherwise I'll accept your answer.